# Administracion de Heap java

Tags: java, excel, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy haciendo un copy paste, desde excel a un `JTable`. El problema es que consume demasiada memoria. He buscado soluciones para hacer ese procedimiento de otras maneras pero no encuentro. Si alguien sabe otra manera de hacerlo se lo agradezco ya que llevo 1 mes buscando e intentando de todo.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public void pegar() {
    Runnable miRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Clipboard clp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

                String total = (String) (clp.getContents(this).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                clp=null;
                StringTokenizer stk1 = new StringTokenizer(total, "\n");
                //dejo total en null
                total = null;
                System.gc();
                dtm.setRowCount(stk1.countTokens());
                int max = 0;
                jProgressBar1.setMaximum(stk1.countTokens());

                ArrayList<String>lista = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; stk1.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {

                    String valor = stk1.nextToken();
                    for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++) {
                        valor = valor.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t \t");
                    }

                    lista.add(valor);

                }
                //dejo el clipboard en null para liberar memoria

                stk1 = null;
                System.gc();
                int size = lista.size();
                //  System.out.println(lista.);

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    StringTokenizer stk2 = new StringTokenizer(lista.get(0), "\t");
                    for (int j = 0; stk2.hasMoreElements(); j++) {
                        String value = stk2.nextToken();
                        jTable1.setValueAt(value, i, j);
                    }
                    lista.remove(0);

                    max++;
                    System.out.println(max);
                    jProgressBar1.setValue(max);
                }
                lista = null;
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

                System.out.println("");
                jProgressBar1.setForeground(new Color(51,0,102));
                System.out.println("me voy a poner en pausa");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("voy a limpiar");

                runtime.gc();
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException|IOException|InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    };
    System.gc();
    hilo = new Thread (miRunnable);
    hilo.start();
}
```

Puse varios gc, pero no sirvieron, leí en SO que el gc no sirve de mucho,mas o menos estoy pegando 5000 filas con 25 columnas y esto es lo que pasa cuando lo pego:

[image: Profile NetBeans]

El heap nunca decrece, se mantiene usando hasta 1gb y yo necesito dejar en uso toda esa memoria, es muy demorado pegando, no sé qué hacer. Si tienen alguna referencia o alguna manera de hacerlo se los agradecería mucho, continuando en el profile, si presiono el botón de recolectar basura en netbeans este inmediatamente disminuye la memoria:

[image: después de presionar el botón]

He aquí una imagen del Excel de donde saco la información a copiar, este archivo tiene 4500 filas y 33 columnas.

[image: Es un ejemplo]

[Documento de excel ejemplo](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnKpE6PYjqHZ22ycV_t4M4js0gTO)

Y este es el jtable donde lo pego.

[image: Java]

PD: soy nuevo en java, todo esto lo hice leyendo y viendo videos.

Comment: Hola mira, simplemente abro el excel con los datos, lo copio y lo pego, ya que la informacion que tenemos en la empresa esta en archivos de excel y no todas las veces se usan todos los registros asi que toca de a pedasos, son archivos de excel con 30 mil registros y se usan de a 4000 o 5000

Comment: No me hago entender, el Excel lo abro en Microsoft Excel, y de ahí lo copio y lo pego en un jtable, el proceso de copiar de Microsoft Excel a java es el que consume esa cantidad de memoria, utilizo el StringTokenizer y trabajo con lo que tengo en el portapapeles

Comment: Oh ok, pensé que era la aplicación quien hacía el trabajo de abrir el archivo Excel. Ahora entiendo mejor tu problema. Veo que primero obtienes toda la cadena a utilizar en memoria y luego la trabajas en dos partes, además que usas un `ArrayList` en el cual ingresas toda la información y luego la borras desde el primero, lo cual sugiere que necesitas una cola y no un areglo dinámico. Adicional, esta cadena parece ser extremadamente grande, y procesarla dos veces parece ser muy costoso en recursos de CPU y memoria.

Comment: Pero como mas podría yo, hacer este proceso?

Comment: Pediría que por favor muestres un ejemplo del archivo excel del que copias el contenido con todas las columnas y un par de filas que reflejen su contenido. Esto serviría para realizar las pruebas necesarias sobre tu código (extrapolándolo a las 5000 líneas que indicas).

Comment: Mira ese ejemplo, ahí esta tal cual manejamos la información siempre, eso se sube a una base de datos en mysql, ya que nuestros clientes nos mandan la base en excel.

Comment: La información del Excel sería mejor como texto y no como imagen. Como te comento, con un par de filas del Excel bastaría, más que nada para conocer la estructura y hacer las pruebas de stress correspondientes.

Comment: Listo, puse un link debajo de el excel que le tome imagen, remplace información importante por otras cosas pero es lo mismo, Muchas Gracias Luiggi.

Comment: He hecho unos cambios a tu código y usando los datos de tu Excel de prueba veo que no usa tanta memoria ni es lento (menos de 1 segundo de ejecución, 123 MBs de memoria). Claro está, en mis cambios no he considerado usar ni `Clipboard` ni `JTable`, para mantener el código "limpio". Quizás el problema esté en el `JTable` o en otro lado. Te recomiendo que al ejecutar tu proceso ejecutes un dump de memoria para analizar dónde está el problema. Asimismo, necesitamos más información sobre tu ambiente: versión de JVM, sistema operativo, RAM asignada a tu proceso, entre otros.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, yo creo que es el `Clipboard`, pero no se que otro metodo usar para copiar, por que hice pruebas con `String.Split, `genere un `for` que ingresaba 5000 registros en el `jTable`, y en efecto eso no consumía mucha memoria, en varias ocasiones me genero error con el `Clipboard`.

Comment: Cierto, no he usado `Clipboard` para mi prueba, en su lugar obtenía toda la cadena desde un archivo de texto que cargaba directo en memoria como un solo String y luego lo mandaba a procesar por tu código. Como te digo, para revisarlo mejor necesitarías obtener un dump de memoria cuando tu proceso está en ejecución y con eso podrás verificar cuál objeto es el que te trae problrmas. Nuevamente, el OS y la versión de JVM que usas también son parte clave en resolver este problema.

Comment: En este momento uso Win 10, pero este software esta destinado a usarse en Win 7, la version de JVM es: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: Si logras obtener un dump de memoria, compártelo por favor para revisarlo y detectar dónde está el problema en tu proceso.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con este código lo he probado hasta con 6000 registros funciona bien aunque ya cuando sobrepasa esa cantidad su rendimiento baja. Espero te sirva.

```
    Workbook wb;

    public String Importar(File archivo, JTable tablaD){
        String respuesta="No se pudo realizar la importación.";
        DefaultTableModel modeloT = new DefaultTableModel();
        tablaD.setModel(modeloT);
        tablaD.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(archivo));//CREAMOS UNA REPRESENTACIÓN DE HOJA EXCEL
            Sheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(0);//SELECCIONAMOS LA HOJA DE LA POSICIÓN -> 0 DEL LIBRO
            Iterator filaIterator = hoja.rowIterator();
            int indiceFila=-1;
            while (filaIterator.hasNext()) {                
                indiceFila++;
                Row fila = (Row) filaIterator.next();
                Iterator columnaIterator = fila.cellIterator();
                Object[] listaColumna = new Object[1000];
                int indiceColumna=-1;
                while (columnaIterator.hasNext()) {                    
                    indiceColumna++;
                    Cell celda = (Cell) columnaIterator.next();
                    if(indiceFila==0){
                        modeloT.addColumn(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }else{
                        if(celda!=null){
                            switch(celda.getCellType()){
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= (int)Math.round(celda.getNumericCellValue());
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getStringCellValue();
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]= celda.getBooleanCellValue();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    listaColumna[indiceColumna]=celda.getDateCellValue();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
                if(indiceFila!=0)modeloT.addRow(listaColumna);
            }
            respuesta="Importación exitosa";
        } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Con más información (Un ejemplo del contenido del excel, por ejemplo), podríamos dar una respuesta más concreta. De momento unos consejos para el uso de RAM en Java (Esto se aplica a todo Java, no solo a Swing):

**1)** No instancies objetos dentro de bucles si lo puedes evitar, por ejemplo:

Este codigo tuyo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    StringTokenizer stk2 = new StringTokenizer(lista.get(0), "\t");
        for (int j = 0; stk2.hasMoreElements(); j++) {
            String value = stk2.nextToken();
            jTable1.setValueAt(value, i, j);
        }
        lista.remove(0);

        max++;
        System.out.println(max);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(max);
}
```

Creas muchos StringTokenizer (stk2) y String (value), sería mejor crearlos una vez fuera y reutilizar las variables:

```
StringTokenizer stk2=null;
String value=null;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    stk2 = new StringTokenizer(lista.get(0), "\t");
        for (int j = 0; stk2.hasMoreElements(); j++) {
            value = stk2.nextToken();
            jTable1.setValueAt(value, i, j);
        }
        lista.remove(0);

        max++;
        System.out.println(max);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(max);
}
```

**2)** Puedes "forzar" a que el Garbage collector de la JVM elimine la "basura" (Variables que has utilizado y ya no utilizas) si limitas la RAM que le das al JVM. Ejemplo:

- El comando -Xmx1024m , limitaría el tamaño del Heap a 1024MB, así "forzando" al Grabage Collector a limpiar la "basura" antes de llegar al limite. (1024 es solo un ejemplo, puedes usar cualquier valor, pero ten en cuenta que esto también puede hacer que el programa deje de funcionar si no tiene suficiente memoria disponible).

Te dejo una guia completa de estos comandos aquí: [Heap Tuning Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html).

*(Seguro que se puede optimizar mucho más, esto son consejos generales que pueden ayudar algo, pero con más información acerca del Excel, más podremos ayudar a reducir el problema de la RAM)*.

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, disculpa mi error al crear variables dentro de el bucle, muchas gracias por la guia.

Comment: Ya puse 2 imágenes nuevas, espero este sea el ejemplo que necesitas, si no es, por fa comentame y te subo lo que necesites, gracias.

Comment: Cuidado con disminuir la memoria. Esto puede generar que hayan más pausas de la JVM puesto que el GC se va a disparar más a menudo. Ahora, el declarar las variables dentro de su alcance es una buena práctica, por lo que declarar el `StringTokenizer` dentro del ciclo `for` no me parece que sea el problema. Yo pienso que debería realizarse una medición del algoritmo y luego revisar otra estrategia más óptima. Según estuve revisando, convendría más usar `Scanner` que `StringTokenizer`, o quizás `String#indexOf` para que sea aún más rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar una solución después de tanto tiempo, espero que sea de ayuda para alguien, ya hice varias pruebas y ya la memoria no se dispara de la misma manera, les dejo el nuevo código que hice:

```
   Clipboard cb;        
   StringSelection contents;
    String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    contents = new StringSelection("Listo");
    cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    cb.setContents(contents, contents);
```

me di cuenta que cuando llamaba el método para obtener el clipboard del sistema, la memoria no subía de inmediato si no a los 5 segundos de iniciado el proceso, entonces lo que hice fue cambiar lo que estaba en el clipboard del sistema dejando algo mas pequeño, y bualá la memoria ya no se subia hasta 1 Gb, puedo copiar 5000 registros de excel y todo perfecto, espero esto le sea de ayuda a alguien, gracias a todos.